# extracting paths from second column in csv files using bash?

Tags: bash

I am trying to extract the second line of information from a csv file that has the following format:

```
1234,//data/sub-1234/ses-Baseline
1235,//data/sub-1235/ses-followup
1236,//data/sub-1234/ses-01
1235,//data/sub-1235/ses-02
```

I have the following script that should work, and it prints out the correct paths when asked. However, it always prints out "Path not found", which points to a problem with the csv file.

```
#!/bin/bash

csv_file="input.csv"

# Skip the first line 
sed '1d' "$csv_file" | while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 rest; do
  if [[ ! -e "$col2" ]]; then
    echo "Path not found: $col2"
  fi
done
```

where the output for a file that exists is still:

```
Path not found: //data/sub-1235/ses-02
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

found a way around the csv problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

input_file="input.txt"

while read -r line; do
    path=$(echo "$line" | cut -f2)
    if ! ls "$path"; then
        echo "Path not found: $path"
    fi
done < "$input_file"
```

Comment: `if ! ls "$path"; then` would produce a presumably undesirable error output from `ls` if the file didn't exist. You could mask that by `if ! ls "$path" 2>/dev/null` but you don't need `ls` here anyway as your original `-e` will work fine once the input issue is fixed, nor do you need a pipe to `cut` for every input line as your original `IFS=,` will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have DOS line endings in your input, see [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Try this (I tidied up a couple of other things too):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

csv_file="input.csv"

# Skip the first line 
while IFS=, read -r _ path; do
  if [[ ! -e "$path" ]]; then
    printf 'Path not found: %s\n' "$path"
  fi
done < <(tail -n +2 "$csv_file" | tr -d '\r')
```

The above assumes any `\r`s in your input are undesirable.